# \insertTableNotes interferes with spacing after caption

Tags: spacing, captions

I have the problem that the spacing between a table caption and the next element (e.g. a new section title) does not directly depend on the position of the caption itself. If I add `\insertTableNotes` before the caption, this space seems to be "subtracted" from the original margin.
In the following example, the spacing between `Table 1` and `Table 2` respectively and the following subsection are not identical. What is the reason?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}           
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    head=20mm,
    left=20mm,
    right=10mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    foot=8mm
}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}     % to have a dedicated notes section after tables
\usepackage[font=small, margin=0pt]{caption}% table and figure captions
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                  % used for table alternatively colors
\usepackage{adjustbox}              % it loads graphicx too

\newenvironment{tableenv}[1]{
    \def\tablelabel{tab:#1}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{footnotesize} 
            % \astroltable
            \begin{ThreePartTable}
}{
        \end{ThreePartTable}
        \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
        % \caption{\tablecaption}
        \label{\tablelabel}
    \end{footnotesize}
\end{center}}
\definecolor{astrol-blue}{HTML}{336699} % Definierung der Farbe gemaess der Astrolfarben

\begin{document}
    \section{Caption Spacing}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}   % distance of box border from content
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}  % box border thicknes
\adjustboxset{width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep\relax,
              valign=c
              }
              
\begin{tableenv}{blabla}
\begin{xltabular}{1.0\textwidth}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}X}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Color} & \textbf{Example}  \\ \midrule
    \endhead
    %\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continue on the next page}}
    Color                       &  blue     &           {\adjustimage{cfbox=blue, width=0.5\linewidth}{example-image-duck}} \\
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Blabla}
\end{xltabular}
\end{tableenv}
\subsection{A new Subsection}
Some text\dots
\begin{tableenv}{blabla}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[1] A note\dots
        \item[2] And another one\dots 
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{xltabular}{1.0\textwidth}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}X}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Color} & \textbf{Example}  \\ \midrule
        \endhead
        %\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continue on the next page}}
        Color                       &  blue     &           {\adjustimage{cfbox=blue, width=0.5\linewidth}{example-image-duck}} \\
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes\\
        \caption{Blabla}
    \end{xltabular}
    \end{tableenv}
    \subsection{A new Subsection}
    Some text\dots

\end{document}
```

**update**:
I still couldn't find a solution, has someone ever encountered a similar issue?

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution, has someone ever encountered a similar issue?

Comment: This is one of the reasones why it is recommended to place table captions aboe the caption not below, then there is room for notes at the end

Comment: Additionally, please specify more clearly what space it is you mean is wrong here. I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: The space between the first table's caption and the next subsection is okay while the space between the second table's caption and the following subsection is smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation gets way better when the `\begin{center}` environment is replaced with the regular layout command `\centering`. So as a matter of fact is what rather the spacing after table 1 that was incorrect.